# Photoshop alternatives for Mac?

Tags: osx, images, image-editor

I'm looking for a program with basic capabilities similar to Photoshop but without the hefty Adobe price-tag.  It needs to run on OSX.

By basic capabilities, I mean things like:

- multi-layer image files,
- support for standard file formats such as .PNG,
- basic editing capabilities, and
- hopefully, effects such as emboss and stroke

Comment: What features are important to you?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Especially missing: What features do you need – what are the "must haves" and the "nice-to-haves"? What is your price limit (or must it come for free as "free beer")?

Comment: Would it help if the OP asked, <p>photo manipulation software; <p>enhance photographs>, <p>enhance images etc.? <p> Or copy & paste Adobe sales copy for Photoshop? I think the question is specific enough and should be reopened. There are several new programs in this space and for this forum to thrive they should be mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

For any platform I cannot recommend [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) enough.

- Cross Platform OS-X, Linux, Windows
- Free, gratis & open source
- Very powerful

You can also extend it with a large number of plug-ins but I would recommend starting with [GMIC](http://gmic.eu/gimp.shtml)

Answer (score 3):

For many years, the main alternative to Photoshop I have found is [Pixelmator](http://www.pixelmator.com/mac/), although the new kid on the block is [Affinity Photo](https://affinity.serif.com/photo/). Both are built for the Mac and are in the $30-40.